# Does http2 allow custom pseudo-header fields?

Tags: http2

Does http2 allow defining custom pseudo-header fields other than :method, :scheme, :authority, and :path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) explicitly forbid to generate custom pseudo-header fields in [this section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2).